# How to get the UID in Firebase using only email

Tags: javascript, php, api, firebase, firebase-authentication

In the control panel of Firebase you can search UID by email [Screenshot to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl2Ht.png)

I am currently using this library to use Firebase SDK using PHP https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-management.html?highlight=users#list-users

Any idea to get the UID of registered users in my project by sending the email parameter without having to download the entire list of users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the code of the library it seems that there is a [`getUserByEmail` method](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/blob/20740bec24943a5a903f9b286405576718918eda/src/Firebase/Auth/ApiClient.php#L81). You should be able to call it like this:

```
$user = $auth->getUserByEmail('user@domain.com');
```

Comment: I approve this message :). Thanks for sifting through the code to find it. I had forgotten to document the method, but fixed this by adding the call in https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-management.html#get-information-about-a-specific-user

Comment: Thanks Jerome. And thanks for maintaining your PHP library so actively. I keep being surprised at how extensive it is.

Comment: It‘s feedback like yours that keeps me going <3